# Finding maxdepth in binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

Here is the code  of binary search tree

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include"malloc.h"

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
int size(struct node* n)
{
    if(n==NULL)
       return 0;
    else
       return (size(n->left)+1+size(n->right));
}

int maxdepth(struct node* n)
{
    int ldepth,rdepth;
    if(n==NULL)
    {
       return 0;
    }
    else
    {
       ldepth=maxdepth(n->left);
       rdepth=maxdepth(n->right);
       if(ldepth>rdepth)
          return (ldepth+1);
       else
          return (rdepth+1);
    }
}

int lookup(struct node* node,int target)
{
    if(node==NULL)
       return 0;
    else if(target==node->data)
       return 1;
    else if(target<node->data)
       return(lookup(node->left,target));
    else
       return(lookup(node->right,target));
}

struct node* newnode(int data)
{
     struct node* newnod=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     newnod->data=data;
     newnod->left=NULL;
     newnod->right=NULL;
     return newnod;
}

struct node* insert(struct node* root,int target)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return(newnode(target));
    else if(target<=root->data)
        root->left=insert(root->left,target);
    else 
        root->right=insert(root->right,target);
    return root;
}

void main()
{
    int result,s,max;
    struct node* newnode=NULL;
    clrscr();
    newnode=insert(newnode,2);
    newnode=insert(newnode,3);
    newnode=insert(newnode,4);
    max=maxdepth(newnode);
    printf("maxdepth %d\n",max);
    s=size(newnode);
    result=lookup(newnode,3);
    printf("size %d\n",s);
    printf("%d",result);
    getch();
}
```

When I runs this program . I get `maxdepth` has 3.

If I change the `maxdepth` function as

```
int maxdepth(struct node* n)
{
    int ldepth,rdepth;
    if(n==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ldepth=maxdepth(n->left);
        rdepth=maxdepth(n->right);
        if(ldepth>rdepth)
            return (ldepth);
        else
            return (rdepth);
    }
}
```

I get the `maxdepth` value as 0. what is the problem? I couldn't not figure it out?

Comment: You seem to like question marks... use 4 spaces or similar to indent your code. having everything left adjusted is not pretty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not counting the current node, so a `+1` is needed.

```
      {
        ldepth = maxdepth(n->left);
        rdepth = maxdepth(n->right);

        if(ldepth > rdepth)
          return ldepth + 1;
        else
          return rdepth + 1;
      }
```

Without the `+1` `maxdepth` always will return `0`. Because `ldepth` and `rdepth` will always be `0`.

An example of a tree with 3 nodes:

```
   A
 /   \
B     C
```

Now you call `maxdepth(A)`, this will do: `ldepth = maxdepth(B); rdepth = maxdepth(C);`, then `maxDepth(B)` will do: `ldepth = maxdepth(null); rdepth = maxdepth(null); /* ldepth and rdepth are now 0 */`, so `maxDepth(B)` will return as a result `0`. Similar `maxDepth(C)` will return `0`. You will do then:

```
if(ldepth > rdepth)
  return ldepth;
else
  return rdepth;
```

But both `ldepth` and `rdepth` are `0`, so `rdepth` will be returned which is `0`. Finally `maxdepth(A)` will return 0 as a result.

That's why `+1` is needed.

Comment: ya i have added +1 in first maxdepth function it returns the depth correctly. but what is wrong if i have not added that +1 it should return me 2 know??? what is going there????

Comment: can u explain me clearly what happens on not adding +1 in maxdepth function..?

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at an example tree:

```
    __A__
   /     \
  B       C
 / \     / \
D   E   F   G
```

In this tree, we're perfectly balanced so we're not going to worry about which is the taller subtree at each node (they're the same height). So we'll just calculate the height using the left branches.

What is the height of the tree? It's the height of `A`.

What is the height of `A`? It's one plus the height of `B`.

In turn, the height of `B` is one plus the height of `D`, and the height of `D` is one plus the height of `D`'s left branch, which is zero.

So total height is `1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 3`.

So the algorithm in this (simplified) case is:

```
def height (node):
    if node is null:
        return 0
    return 1 + height (node.left)
```

And *that's* why your recursive height function has to add one at each level. If instead you add 0 (which is what your second code segment is doing), you switch from getting `1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 3` to getting `0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0`.

If you modify the algorithm above to take into account different sizes of subtrees, you basically get your first code segment, which works fine:

```
def height (node):
    if node is null:
        return 0
    leftheight = height (node.left)
    rightheight = height (node.rigth)
    return 1 + max (leftheight, rightheight)
```